# Como usar uma function PHP dentro de uma function JS

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho uma função em PHP(eu li que era recomendado fazer modificações no banco de dados em PHP e não em JS)

```
function insertTable()
    {

        $name = 'nome';
        $categoria = 'categoria';
        $download = 1000;
        $upload = 1000;
        $magnet = 'magnet';

        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO torrents(`Nome`, `Categoria`, `DownloadQuantity`, `UploadQuantity`, `Magnet`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$categoria."', ".$download.", ".$upload.", '".$magnet."')");
    }
```

E na minha função em JS(ela esta na `action` de um botão) eu quero chamar a função `insertTable()`.

Eu li que o PHP é executado no servidor e o JS e executado no navegador, a unica forma que achei foi quando a função em PHP esta em um arquivo separado, assim usando AJAX, porem eu quero fazer isso com as duas funções no mesmo arquivo.

Comment: @Miguel Desculpe, acho o Stack deu uma cortada nela, já arrumei :D

Comment: Sem problema, foi mais pela piada.. Já apaguei o comentário

Comment: No mesmo arquivo, só se fizer a requisição AJAX para o próprio e tratá-la com o PHP. Porém, como o arquivo iria receber tanto requisições 'normais' e via AJAX, com o PHP você terá que se preocupar em não retornar o HTML para quando for AJAX. Sinceramente, não vejo motivos para fazer isso, sem contar que deixa a organização do projeto confusa.

Comment: Estou pelo celular, então não posso colocar o código agora. Eu uso ajax para colocar uma div na página ao pressionar um botao, e quando esse botao é pressionado tenho que inserir dados no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Javascript não tem como acessar seu banco de dados, então o comando só pode ser feito por um script que rode no servidor, no caso o PHP, a solução é fazer uma requisição ajax, ou ainda um POST/GET de um formulario, como você quer ficar na mesma pagina, acho que é mais pratico o AJAX, mas nos dois casos o funcionamento é o mesmo:

- Sua pagina requisita um link
- Este link executa o comando no banco

Você quer que tudo fique no mesmo "arquivo"? Faça um "if" no arquivo validando algum parâmetro passado pelo seu AJAX ou POST/GET ($_FORM[seu parametro) que avise seu arquivo o que fazer.

Não é bonito, mas funciona, porém a menos que tenha alguma especie de controle de acesso, seria no mínimo uma falha de segurança na sua aplicação

Comment: Antes de responder pesquise se já não existe resposta em outra pergunta que resolva o problema, exemplo de pesquisa que retorna vários resultados http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+server-side+javascript+client-side

Comment: Quem teria que fazer isso não é quem pergunta?

Comment: Sim também, é dever todos manterem a comunidade organizada, tanto eu, quanto você quanto o autor. Só que o autor não conhecia a resposta e você sim, para você achar qual é a resposta adequada existente é mais fácil do que para ele que não tem a minima noção, compreende? Até mais ;)